# Post isnt created, image canot be loaded. ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone help please. Trying to add image in post, but post doesnt create.
The error : Can't resolve image into URL: to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil.

and problem shows in this line :

```
 <%= image_tag post.image , class: 'main-image' %>
```

I have this form:

```
<%= form_for Post.new do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, class:'d-none'%>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="text-center">
    <%= f.submit 'Create Post', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And this in my html file

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <section class="post">
  <div class="user">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="user_avatar.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="username">
      <%= post.user.username %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= image_tag post.image , class: 'main-image' %>

  <div class="description">
    <%= post.description %>
  </div>
</section>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :image


 validate :image_presence
   def image_presence
     errors.add(:image, "can't be blank") unless image.attached?
   end

end  
------
post.rb
```

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    Post.create(post_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:description, :image, :user_id)
  end

end
------
post_controller
```

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
--------
storage.yml
```

Have this in development.rb
 `config.active_storage.service = :local`

Comment: What happens if `Post.create` fails? Have a look at [this example from Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters).

Comment: I dont get this message "can't be blank". If I delete this line frome code " <%= image_tag post.image , class: 'main-image' %>"  the post can be created without image, and I can see all my previos tryes of creating(posts) without images

Comment: Tried it. The same mistake.. without any changes. I can assume that post doesnt go throu the validation, because i dont see my error message, but why?

Comment: Can you post your `storage.yml` and `config.active_storage.service` on `environments/development.rb`

Comment: yes, i added this inf in main post

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the form to be a multipart form https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

```
<%= form_for Post.new, multipart: true do |f| %>
```

If the form is not multipart it will not send the file.

Comment: tried it, it doesnt work for me. the same problem